# Flexbox column wrap fill horizontal space with rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I have a simple flex box inside a div that currently shows up like

```
item 1
item 2
item 3
item 4
item 5
item 6
item 7
item 8
```

leaving a lot of empty space on the right and filling down infinitely

I want something more like

```
item 1     item 3      item 6     item 8
item 2     item 4      item 7
```

where the items are ordered in downward order but it creates columns to fill the empty horizontal space

I would not like to specify any widths or heights here if possible. I would like the rows to be able to expand downwards infinitely if there are many items, and I would like the column widths to expand to the size of the largest item in the column

If an item has a very long text inside it that takes up half the vertical space, I would like the column that it is in to take up half the vertical space

Here is my very simple code so far

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">item 2</div>
    ...
</div>

-- CSS --
.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;

    .item {
        // nothing so far
    }
}
```

I've tried using flex-basis:25% to try and create 4 columns but it didn't work

I also tried setting flex-grow to 1 and flex-shrink to 0, but it didn't change anything

Any ideas here?
Thanks

Comment: You need to limit the height of the container so the items know when to wrap.

Comment: but I want the container to have infinite height if there were say 1 million items.

I want the items to wrap as far horizontally as they can basically

Comment: As I said, you don't get wrapping unless the height is limited in some way. If the container had infinite height you would just get a single infinite height column with **no** wrapping.

Comment: Maybe let's consider this problem differently. Let's say I used `row wrap` instead of `column wrap` for the flex flow. This would create the layout that I want. But I would want the items to be ordered by column. Currently the first 4 items are in the first row. Is there a way that I can change the ordering axis?

Comment: Nope... not without setting heights/widths in some way.

Comment: Okay, sounds good, thanks.

I guess the solution is then to dynamically calculate the height in order to limit the div

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Comment: This does what I want it to do, thanks